# Is it possible to restrict clipboard access to specific processes?

Tags: operating-systems, data-leakage, clipboard

I'm not sure if somebody has implemented this before, but I think it'd be helpful if we can make certain clipboard messages only available to specific processes if they are not meant to be public.

Is this technique already available on some platforms, or an ongoing work, or deemed unnecessary in favor of other IPC techniques (and if the latter what they are)?

Answer (score 1):

[Sandboxie](https://www.sandboxie.com/) is a [sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(software_development)) program that has this [capability.](https://forums.sandboxie.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=184)

Answer (score 0):

That's really application specific and depending on operation system you can hook into those events within the application and inspect content prior to passing to the clipboard.

Try [WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dataxchg/wm-clipboardupdate)